# show vector elements in listbox

Tags: listbox, c++-cli

I would like to display the elements in a vector in a listbox. However, I'm constantly getting a error: error C2664: 'System::Windows::Forms::ListBox::ObjectCollection::Add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'System::Object ^'

I am using windows form in c++/cli.
 this is the code:

```
for (size_t z = 0; z < container.size(); z++){
        listBox_name->Items->Add(container[z]);
    }
```

Comment: This is about C++/CLI not C++ - they are **not** the same thing. You're likely to get responses if you properly tag your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, your vector is a vector of `std::string`. Use `marshal_as` to convert the `std::string` to a managed `String^` that the managed list box can accept.

```
for (size_t z = 0; z < container.size(); z++){
    listBox_name->Items->Add(marshal_as<String^>(container[z]));
}
```

If you find you're doing this a lot, consider changing your vector of `std::string` to be a fully-managed type, such as `List<String^>^`.