# Adding elements from vector to listBox in c++

Tags: vector, listbox, c++-cli

Im new programmer, learning **C++** nearly `15` weeks so far and I'm doing a small project about student `database` with `GUI` ( `Windows-forms` ). I created `GUI` with `Drag` n `Drop` thing in **Visual Studio 2015**.

I have `class` Student with `13` `variables` including `getters` and `setters` (`Index`, `First Name`,`Last name`, etc...). I've successfully opened connection with **MySQL** `database` for Adding, Deleting and Update students.
And I also wrote objects `String^` to pick text from my `TextBoxes` and then parse them into normal string with `msclr`/`marshal`.

Now, problem is when i create object of Student and after adding it into `vector` with `code` below:

```
vector<Student> vektor;

Student *s = new Student(iIndeks, cIme, cPrezime, cDatumRodjenja, cFakultet, cSmer, cEmail, iBrTelefona, cDrzava, cMesto, cUlicaIBroj, cOpstina, iPostanskibr);

vektor.push_back(*s);
```

Im unable to add elements of that vector into `listBox` with:

```
listBox1->Items->Add(vektor);
```

It says this `error`:

Function cannot be called with given argument list,
`argument` `types` are:

`(std::vector<Student, std::allocator<Student>>)` `object` `type` is:

`System::Windows::Forms::ListBox::ObjectCollection ^`.

I guess its pretty self-explaining but I have no idea (should I or not) create my class like the ref class or something like that?
Any suggestion what this newbie can do?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show vector elements in listbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001897/show-vector-elements-in-listbox)

Comment: I've tried that but then I get another error:
C2065: This conversation is not supported.

             _To_Type=System::String ^,
              _From_Type=Student

If I resolve my current error, then I get another new one..

Comment: List box should list some strings, so give him strings. Because `ListBox` is part of .NET it requires `String^`, so give him that instead of `std::string` or `Student`.

Comment: Actually, it's `marshal_as<String^>()` function that requires something that is some kind of C++ string, either `std::string` or `const char*`, so provide that as function argument, instead of `Student`.

Comment: Let me just explain here what I've imagined in my head. Clicking button "Save student", it opens connection with database and adds student into database(that part works) and in same time, to create new object type of Student and then add it as object into vector. Then I want to "print" content of vector (at least on that List Box) to make sure object is added into vector. Maybe it sounds a bit confusing but I don't know how to explain better. I'm sorry.

Comment: In `for` loop, or `for_each` loop, make a `std::string` that is the content of one item that you want to see, and use `marshal_as<String^>()` to convert that `std::string` into `String^`, and feed the list box with that `String^`.

Comment: Okay, that worked. Thank you so much! Just other thing. Is there any way to "print" elements of vector ( in my case object of class Student) in some Box or custom Form or anything similar? Because I need to make sure that my vector works and keeps those object elements.

Comment: Make sure that order of items in `ListBox` is the same as in the `vector`, and when user selects an item in the `ListBox` take the corresponding `Student` from the vector and show the values of its members. You will have to make the `Form` by hand. Add all the `TextBox`es you want, and populate them in `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.